# Math date algorithm required

Tags: javascript, algorithm, date

Embarrassingly enough I need a small algorithm

I am helping with a site where gif B is shown on the first of July, C on the third and A on the fifth. Then b again on the seventh and so on - a,b,c changing every second day at 8 in the morning

So how do I use a simple algo to make this script return 0, 1 or 2 depending on how many days since the 1st of July

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/T2Tjh/

```
var startDate = new Date(2012,6,1,8,0,0); 
var pics = ["b.gif","c.gif","a.gif"];
var aDay = 24*60*60*1000;
function getDateDiff(startDate,endDate) {
  var diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
  return Math.round(diff/aDay);
}
document.write('<br/>'+getDateDiff(startDate,new Date()));
```

Comment: ... modulo 3? I don't understand the question otherwise, your code works fine.

Comment: @minitech modulo 3 only works when images are changing *every* day. But they are changing every **second** day. This makes it a bit more difficult. See HopeIHelped's answer.

Comment: @freakish: ... divide by two, modulo 3? You're right, that is a *bit* more difficult.

Comment: @minitech Are you asking me? :) I did know the answer from the very begining.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
var startDate = new Date(2012, 6, 1, 8, 0, 0);
var pics = ["b.gif", "c.gif", "a.gif"];
var aDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

function getDateDiff(startDate, endDate) {
    var diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
    return Math.round(diff / aDay);
}
document.write('<br/>' + pics[Math.floor(getDateDiff(startDate, new Date()) / 2) % 3]);
```

Comment: Ah, but there is a small issue. What if you divide (for example) `(11/2)%3`? You will obtain `2.5`. You need to wrap everything with (for example) `parseInt` before taking modulo.

Comment: @freakish: Not `parseInt`, that's for parsing strings. Use `Math.floor`. Or `(x | 0)`. (Well yes, `parseInt` would work. But it feels wrong. Anyway, that's right.)

Comment: @minitech Obviously you don't know that `parseInt` works with numbers as well. And it is more efficient then both `Math.floor` and `(x|0)`.

Comment: @freakish: Actually, I knew the former perfectly well. The latter I *didn't* know, partially because [it's not true](http://jsperf.com/parseint-versus-floor-versus-or-zero) on my browser, and if it's not true on a mainstream browser, then there is no point in using one over the other except for semantics - and `parseInt` doesn't really make sense when speaking in the context of rounding a float is all. Just personal preference :)

Comment: @minitech Oops, you're right. Actually I was looking at similar figures and somehow I thought that they were showing the time, not ops/sec. I stand corrected!

Answer (score -2):

You'll want to use the [modulo operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.C2.A0.25_%28Modulus%29) here:

```
document.write('<br/>'+getDateDiff(startDate,new Date())%3);
```

Comment: -1: unfortunetly this is not as obvious as it looks like. Read the question and HopeIHelped's answer carefully.